# How to add PFObjects with different class names to one relation

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

in my project I have a user relation for the key userPosts. I want to add to this relation different objects with different class names, in this example a category from a UIPicker, something like this:

```
PFObject *post = [PFObject objectWithClassName:selectedCategory];
//do stuff with the object...
[object save];
PFRelation *relation = [PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"userPosts"];
[relation addObject:post];
[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to execute this code it throws me a runtime error saying basically that I can only add objects to a relation with one class name. How do I override/fix it? Thanks :)

Comment: I am not having any problems executing your code. Please post the exact errors you are getting and at which point they occur.

Comment: You already posted this question. Please don't ask the same question twice

Comment: @freshking This is the error message I'm getting: reason: 'Related object object must be of class GeneralPosts, but (other category) was passed in' GeneralPosts is the first category I've used so it basically says all of the objects have to be from this class...